# PHPUnit 3.7.14 by Sebastian Bergmann. unrecognized option --skeleton-test

Tags: unit-testing, netbeans, phpunit

I am trying to use netbeans (7.2.1) for unit testing. But it is giving me this error. anyone can tell me what is wrong in it?

```
PHPUnit 3.7.14 by Sebastian Bergmann. unrecognized option --skeleton-test
```

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon this problem too. It's solved in NetBeans 7.3, but if you are still using 7.2, here is the solution:

1. Install phpunit-skelgen as mentioned in the other answers. If you are using pear: `sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator`
2. In NetBeans, open the unit testing options: Tools > Options > PHP > Unit Testing
3. Click on the Search button for the skeleton generator field (or you can just browse of course)

That solved it for me.
This issue is documented in the NetBeans issue tracker right here: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=218675

Comment: pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator - No releases available for package "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator"
install failed

Answer (score 0):

The newer PHPUnit does not use the --skeleton-test option.  You call an external script, phpunit-skelgen to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the `phpunit-skelgen` file exists in the same directory as the phpunit binary (eg. `/opt/lampp/bin/`).

If not, install the *PHPUnit SkeletonGenerator* the same way you installed PHPUnit, eg. from PEAR:

```
$ sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator
```